# Что нужно для работы Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Есть ли список ПО, которые нужно установить для работы Visual Studio? Например, .NET Core и Visual C++. Я решил почистить диск от ненужных программ и теперь установленная Visual Studio 2019 вылетает при запуске без ошибки, а установщик с официального сайта просто выключается после извлечения в Temp. Пытался удалить visual studiо, но Visual Studio Installer просит обновление, а после его загрузки выключается.

Comment: я думаю, тут почти никто не угадает, что именно Вы и как именно снесли. А полный список всех зависимостей вряд ли кто то сделает. Поэтому, наиболее простой способ - удалить всю студию и поставить заново

Comment: Ну, удалил я как раз таки несколько Visual C++ 2010-2017. Ну не суть, тогда подскажите, как удалить студию, если, запуская удаление через Программы и Компоненты, установщик просит обновление и выключается при нажатии Обновить?

Comment: подозреваю, что Вы удалили немного больше, чем нужно. У меня обычно это заключалось в переустановке операционной системы

Comment: И еще установщик тоже не работает, вылетает после распаковки без ошибок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, скачав другую IDE.